# Removing sound in a Powerpoint presentation

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, recording

I have prepared a powerpoint presentation and have added some oral support using the diaporama tool on the upper bar. Now, I want to generate the same presentation, but without the oral part, in order to recover the original version of my presentation.

So, how can I do ?

Thank you

Comment: First, Mac or Windows (or web/mobile version)?
Next, do you mean that you used the record narration feature? If so, a bit of VBA could do this for you, I think.  Awaiting your reply.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all sound transitions from the presentation :

- Open the presentation
- Position to the Transitions pane
- In the Timing group, set "Sound:" to "[No Sound]"
- Click "Apply To All"
- That's it.

You could also delete all the audio file, if they are still left
inside the presentation folder.